# how to upload image to database using php, undefined index:images

Tags: php

anyone can help my task in school, i confused that.. the image cant store to database.

```
<form action="doOrder.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Category : T-SHIRT

Choose Size
<label for="sizes"><span>
<input type="radio" name="sizes" value="S" checked="checked"/>S
<input type="radio" name="sizes" value="M" />M
<input type="radio" name="sizes" value="L" />L
<input type="radio" name="sizes" value="XL" />XL
</span>
</label>

Fabric Type
<select name="fabric">
    <option value="Cotton Combed">Cotton Combed</option>
    <option value="Cotton Carded">Cotton Carded</option>
   <option value="Polyester / PE">Polyester / PE</option>
    </select>

Total
<input type="number" name="total" min="1" max="100">
<input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload">
<input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and this the doOrder.php

```
<?php 
    require_once("connect.php");

    $nama_file = $_FILES['images']['name'];
    $sizes = $_POST['sizes'];
    $fabric = $_POST['fabric'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['images']['name']);


    $simpan = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pesanan(category, sizes, fabric, total,images) VALUES('T-SHIRT','$sizes','$fabric','$total','$nama_file')");

    echo "Your add has been submited....";

?>
```

the error is that

> Notice: Undefined index: images  on line 4 Notice: Undefined index:
>   images in on line 9 Notice: Undefined index: images in on line 9

Comment: Your `<input type="file"/>` has `name="imageUpload"`, why are you referring to it in PHP as `$_FILES['images']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key images does not exist in the files array. `imageUpload` is what you passed as the name attribute from the html form. So that's what you access

```
$nama_file = $_FILES['imageUpload']['name'];//imageUpload

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['imageUpload']['name']);
```

Also please add validations to your file upload module. As it is Trojans and other harmful files can easily be uploaded

Answer (score 1):

You actually try to access the form-input with name "images" - it doesn't exist. In your form, the field is named as "imageUpload"

So change:

```
$nama_file = $_FILES['images']['name'];
```

To:

```
$nama_file = $_FILES['imageUpload']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the name  of the input field in :

which is imageUpload

change this : `$nama_file = $_FILES['images']['name'];` to this

```
$nama_file = $_FILES['imageUpload']['name'];
```

also :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

to :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['imageUpload']['name']);
```